Optional function name prefix with clang tidy?
I'm using the clang tidy readability-input-naming rule in a project to enforce function name style as CamelCase. However, there is a need to be able to specify an optional prefix for some functions whilst continuing to enforce the readability-input-naming rule:
// Current style:
void DoSomething(void);

// What I need to allow:
void Win32_DoSomething(void);
void Linux_DoSomething(void);

Using the ignore regex to ignore function names starting with Win32_ or Linux_ is not an option because that would prevent the readability-input-naming rule being applied to the function. Disabling the lint for the line with NOLINTNEXTLINE(readability-input-naming) is not an option because it will also prevent the rule from being applied.
Is it possible to have an optional prefix?

I don't use clang-tidy, but doesn't it allow you to disable a specific rule on a per-function basis?

It does, e.g // NOLINTNEXTLINE but I'd still like the rest of the rules to be followed, which is why I'm wondering if there's a way to specify an optional prefix, e.g. with a regex of something.

That disables all rules. Isn't there a way to just disable the readability-input-naming rule for the next line?

I have edited the question to hopefully be clearer, but to summarise: I would like to allow optional prefixes to function names without disabling the readability-input-naming lint.

clang-tidy readability-input-naming has a "Function Prefix" option, but it seems to force you to use the prefix unfortunately. https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability/identifier-naming.html#cmdoption-arg-FunctionPrefix I don't know if this option supports a regex - if it does, it could still solve your problem I think.

How are these prefixed identifiers distributed in your source tree? If only specific source use that prefix, julaine's suggestion looks promising. If you have mixed identifiers in the same source, you might want to reconsider your software design.

I think the suggestion you’re making is to have a main clang tidy configuration file and then override that locally where I want the rules to differ? I think that’ll work, and I didn’t ask for a solution that has just one config file, although that would be preferred.
